# SSH into DCOS master on Azure asks for password

Tags: ssh, azure, cloud-computing, apache-mesos

I just set up a DC/OS cluster on Azure. I basically just followed the instructions from the [Install Guide](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/installing/evaluation/azure/). So far so good, everything works as expected.

Terraform config used to install DC/OS:

```
variable "dcos_install_mode" {
  description = "specifies which type of command to execute. Options: install or upgrade"
  default = "install"
}

data "http" "whatismyip" {
  url = "http://whatismyip.akamai.com/"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~> 1.16.0"
}

module "dcos" {
  source  = "dcos-terraform/dcos/azurerm"
  version = "~> 0.1.0"

  dcos_instance_os    = "coreos_1855.5.0"
  cluster_name        = "dcos-sandbox"
  ssh_public_key_file = "~/.ssh/dcos-sandbox@azure.pub"
  admin_ips           = ["${data.http.whatismyip.body}/32"]
  location            = "West Europe"

  num_masters        = "1"
  num_private_agents = "3"
  num_public_agents  = "0"

  masters_vm_size = "Standard_D2s_v3"
  private_agents_vm_size = "Standard_B2s"
  public_agents_vm_size = "Standard_B2s"

  dcos_version = "1.12.0"

  # dcos_variant              = "ee"
  # dcos_license_key_contents = "${file("./license.txt")}"
  dcos_variant = "open"

  providers = {
    azurerm = "azurerm"
  }

  dcos_install_mode = "${var.dcos_install_mode}"
}

output "masters-ips" {
  value       = "${module.dcos.masters-ips}"
}

output "cluster-address" {
  value       = "${module.dcos.masters-loadbalancer}"
}

output "public-agents-loadbalancer" {
  value = "${module.dcos.public-agents-loadbalancer}"
}
```

Now I need to SSH into the master node. According to the docs I should be able to just execute

```
dcos node ssh --master-proxy --leader
```

But for some reason the master node does not accept my public key and asks for a password instead.

The debug output for

```
ssh -A -t  -l core <master-ip> -vvv -i ~/.ssh/dcos-sandbox@azure -- ssh -A -t  -l core 172.12.0.7 --
```

is as follows

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname <master-ip> is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to <master-ip> [<master-ip>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/roman/.ssh/dcos-sandbox@azure type 0
debug1: identity file /home/roman/.ssh/dcos-sandbox@azure-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to <master-ip>:22 as 'core'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/roman/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/roman/.ssh/known_hosts:55
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from <master-ip>
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:XyFTmZCV1ZW9ddDK7QP/Q0Bdix5KFgxUwQYcZOmmk6A
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/roman/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/roman/.ssh/known_hosts:55
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from <master-ip>
debug1: Host '<master-ip>' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/roman/.ssh/known_hosts:55
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/roman/.ssh/dcos-sandbox@azure RSA SHA256:rup1zxdhaB5+ADImcbpI9wzEfli8Jr/8tXgQ18XubBo explicit agent
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/roman/.ssh/dcos-sandbox@azure RSA SHA256:rup1zxdhaB5+ADImcbpI9wzEfli8Jr/8tXgQ18XubBo explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
```

Apparently my SSH client is offering the SSH key which I used when I installed DC/OS using terraform.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, the docs seem to be unclear on this point. The docs imply the default user to be "core" when using coreOS. This is wrong. Terraform sets the admin user to "dcos_admin".

I was finally able to ssh into the master node with

```
dcos node ssh --master-proxy --leader --user=dcos_admin
```